# Using Amdahl's law and time to calculate amount of processors?

Tags: parallelism-amdahl

Let's say I have a program T that has a serial portion that consumes 355 s, and a parallel portion that uses 645 s.

How can I find out how many processors I need so that the program T's parallel run time is less than or equal to 51% of its serial run time?

Comment: By solving the equation.  It is simple (high-school) algebra.  (Of course ... that is a theoretical answer.  In practice you can rarely get N-fold speedup with N processors.)

Comment: @StephenC Using Amdahl's formula, how would you solve this? I've only learned it using Speedup = 1/ 1-p + p/s, but i'm having a hard time using the values in my problem and plugging them into the original formula.